# Minimum heap size in JVM (-Xms)

Tags: java, memory, jvm, heap-memory

Despite setting the minimum heap size to 0 and observing successful program execution, the question arises: With the JVM's dynamic resizing capabilities, is there a compelling need for a minimum heap size?

What is the need for a minimum heap size? Even though we have a maximum heap size, why do we need a minimum heap size when it can start at zero? I'm looking for concrete reason behind minimum heap size. Jvm itself resizes whenever it needs, then what is the contribution of minimum heap size.

Comment: maybe it is better to see it as *initial* heap size - see the following question and its answers [What are the -Xms and -Xmx parameters when starting JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14763079/85421)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10605133/6650475).

Comment: It is a tuning option for the startup performance. If you start an application with an initial heap size that is too low it will: run out of memory, the garbage collector will try to free memory (maybe several times), then the heap size will be increased. This cycle (OOM, n times GC, heap size increase) may be repeated several times until the heap size is large enough and can be avoided if you set a meaningful initial heap size. Having said that: for most of my applications I don't bother to set an initial heap size - it's just to much effort if the application startup time doesn't matter.